# Positioning custom AppBar without SafeArea

Tags: flutter, flutter-appbar, safearea

I am trying to create a custom `AppBar`, with a polygon instead of the bar, I already have something:

[image]

As you can see, on some screens the bar is to high, because the SafeArea differs. I did not use:

```
child: Scaffold(
    appBar: MyCustomBar(),
    body: // my body
)
```

I wrote followings, which is a `Stack` where the bar is on top with a fixed height and a padding (`SafeArea`), and the main view takes the entire height with a padding on top:

```
child: Scaffold(
    body: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        children: [
            Flex(direction: Axis.vertical, children: [
            Flexible(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: padding,
                            right: padding,
                            top: padding + StatusBar.getHeight(),
                            bottom: padding),
                        child: Column(
                          children: children,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
            )
          ]),
          MyCustomBar(
            title,
            iconLeft: iconLeft,
            iconRight: iconRight,
          ),
        ]
    ),
)
```

where `static const padding = 15.0;` which is obviously the problem, it worked fine for most of the Android devices, but I needs to be dynamic based on the `SafeArea` of each device.

Why I decided to do it this way? Because I have a polygon as a bar and the text has to be visible where the bar is intended to be transparent:

[image]

The first solution I have in mind is to get the top padding of the `SafeArea` and using it instead my static variable. The problem is that I am not able to get the padding if I am not using the `SafeArea`.

If I refactor my code following [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-increase-the-power-of-your-appbar-sliverappbar-c4f67c4e076f) example in order to use the `Scaffold.appBar`, I get the following result:

[image]

IMHO I don't know if it is possible to achieve it using the `SafeArea.appBar`.

Any hint to fix my `MyCustomBar`?

**EIDT**:
I just found this:

```
Scaffold.extendBodyBehindAppBar
```

This allows me to use the Scaffold.appBar.

Comment: What did you wrap with the `SafeArea`? The entire `Stack`?

Comment: In my code I did not use the SafeArea. In the refactored one yes, as the linkt i posted says.

Comment: Can you wrap your `flex` component with a `Positioned` widget and add a value on to `top` property based on `MediaQuery`?

Comment: Don't really get it. The `Flex` component is already on top of the `Stack`.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your stack inside a column

Comment: Please be more specific. Maybe with a snippet.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

simply use `SliverAppBar` instead if you want to use custom appbar.

But you need to use `CustomScrollView` as wrapper

Comment: Sorry but I don't get it. Why shoud I use a SliverAppBar?

Comment: SliverAppBar gives you many customization, you can expand appbar, and you can position your appbar easily.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to fix it using the standard `AppBar`. Two things I did not where the `AppBar.shape` and the `Scaffold.extendBodyBehindAppBar` properties:

```
Scaffold(
  extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
  appBar: MyCustomAppBar(),
  body: Flex(direction: Axis.vertical, children: [
    Flexible(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: kToolbarHeight + MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top),
          child: Column(children: children),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ]),
);
```

I skip the code of `MyCustomAppBar`, here just the `AppBar`:

```
AppBar(
  centerTitle: true,
  titleSpacing: 0,
  actions: [myAction],
  title: myTitle,
  backgroundColor: anyColor,
  leading: myLeading,
  automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
  shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
      bottomLeft: Radius.lerp(const Radius.elliptical(100, 10),
        const Radius.elliptical(100, 10), 0)!,
      bottomRight: Radius.lerp(const Radius.elliptical(50, 10),
        const Radius.elliptical(50, 10), 0)!
    ),
  ),
);
```

Here the result:

[image]

Hope to help somebody.